# insert into mysql database with pymysql failing to insert

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to insert dummy data into a mysql database.

The database structure looks like:

`database name: messaround
database table name: test`

table structure:

`id (Primary key, auto increment)
path (varchar(254))`

**UPDATED 2** method below, and error.
I have a method to try to insert via:

```
def insert_into_db(dbcursor, table, *cols, **vals):
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ('{}')".format(table, ",".join(cols),  "'),('".join(vals))  
        print(query)
        dbcursor.execute(query)
        dbcursor.commit()
        print("inserted!")
    except pymysql.Error as exc:
        print("error inserting...\n {}".format(exc))

connection=conn_db()        
insertstmt=insert_into_db(connection, table='test', cols=['path'], vals=['test.com/test2'])
```

However, this is failing saying:

```
INSERT INTO test () VALUES ('vals'),('cols')
error inserting...
 (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

Can you please assist?

Thank you.

Comment: I see the path comes from 'vals' which are characters but not numbers. you should wrap the vals with quotes like "path_val"

Comment: @UdayS - can you put this into an answer so I can see more clearly please.

Answer (score 2):

If you use your code:

```
def insert_into_db(dbcursor, table, *cols, **vals):
    query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(table,",".join(cols), ",".join(vals))
    print(query)

insert_into_db('cursor_here', 'table_here', 'name', 'city', name_person='diego', city_person='Sao Paulo')
```

Python returns:

```
INSERT INTO table_here (name,city) VALUES (name_person,city_person)
```

Now with this other:

```
def new_insert_into_db(dbcursor, table, *cols, **vals):
    vals2 = ''
    for first_part, second_part in vals.items():
        vals2 += '\'' + second_part + '\','
    vals2 = vals2[:-1]
    query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(table,",".join(cols), vals2)
    print(query)

new_insert_into_db('cursor_here', 'table_here', 'name', 'city', name_person='diego', city_person='Sao Paulo')
```

Python will return the correct SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table_here (name,city) VALUES ('diego','Sao Paulo')
```

Comment: appreciate the answer. is it possible to make this less convoluted? Like, is it possible to make it easier to read with less concatentation?

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Python you pass a parameterized query to the DB driver. See [this example in PyMySQL's documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html#crud); it constructs the `INSERT` query with placeholder characters, then calls `cursor.execute()` passing the query, and a tuple of the actual values.

Using parameterized queries is also [recommended for security purposes](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet), as it defeats many common SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

you should print the sql statement which you've generated, that makes it a lot easier to see what's wrong.

But I guess you need quotes `'` around string values for your `",".join(vals)` (in case there are string values.
So your code is producing

```
insert into test (path,) values (test.com/test2,);
```

but it should produce

```
insert into test (`path`) values ('test.com/test2');
```

Otherwise try https://github.com/markuman/MariaSQL/ which makes it super easy to insert data to MariaDB/MySQL using pymysql.

Comment: Did you see my `insertstmt` ? It includes a `path` as a string at the end.

Comment: No, because `vals = ['test.com/test2,']` becomes after `"values ({})".format(",".join(vals))`  just `'values (test.com/test2,)'`. but it needs something like `"'" + ",".join(vals) + "'"`.

Comment: Please see updated code, and output. This still isnt working.

Comment: I see no updated snippet. Also, the mysql error message says exactly this: 

> ... near 'test.com/test2,) VALUES ()' at line 1")

you're missing quotes. And, at least when you're using special characters in  columnnames, you need to use backticks for it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/markuman/d620fb3130d0966307ac71ef728f9381 this is how you python string should look like in the end, but it looks like this `insert into test (path,) values (test.com/test2,);`

Comment: why doesnt `values` value include any quotes around it?

Comment: Because you `",".join()` just creates a new string. It does not glue quoted strings to eachother

Comment: Ok, can you update your answer please? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as below

```
query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ('{}')".format(table, ",".join(cols),  "'),('".join(vals))
```

As you are using join, the variable is expected to be a list but not a string

```
table = 'test'
cols = ['path']
vals = ['test.com/test2', 'another.com/anothertest']


print(query)

"INSERT INTO test (path) VALUES ('test.com/test2'),('another.com/anothertest')"
```

Update:

```
def insert_into_db(dbconnection=None, table='', cols=None, vals=None):
    mycursor = dbconnection.cursor()
    if not (dbconnection and table and cols and vals):
        print('Must need all values')
        quit()
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ('{}')".format(table, ",".join(cols),  "'),('".join(vals))
        mycursor.execute(query)
        dbconnection.commit()
        print("inserted!")
    except pymysql.Error as exc:
        print("error inserting...\n {}".format(exc))


connection=conn_db()        

insertstmt=insert_into_db(dbconnection=connection, table='test', cols=['path'], vals=['test.com/test2'])
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but how can I execute this via the variable `insertstmt` as I show above?

Comment: please see updated code an error for **UPDATE2** above

Comment: still struggling to formulate this, please see `UPDATE2` above.